# Insert into MYSQL Database WHERE username = :username

Tags: php, mysql

So, im struggling with this for 2 days, i havent seen any example on google about that it works, so i guess it doesnt work like this:

```
$steamusername = "xx";
$uname = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO users (steamusername) VALUES ( :steamusername) WHERE :username = username";

$query = $conn->prepare( $sql1 );
$result = $query->execute( array( ':steamusername'=>$steamusername, ':username'=>$uname));
```

It does not give any errors, but it also does not put it into the database.

I really have no idea how i can make it it goes into the user table, i also tried to update the field:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE users SET steamusername = :steamusername WHERE username = :username";
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
$stmt1->bindParam(':username', $uname);
$stmt1->bindValue(':steamusername', $steamusername);
$stmt1->execute();
```

Does anyone know the solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about INSERT ....WHERE and how would that work

Comment: Actually it might very well give an error. You wouldn't know, since you're not checking for one. Try `if (!($stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1))) { throw new Exception($stmt1->error); }` and `if ($stmt1->execute()) { throw new Exception($stmt1->error); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT` is used to create a new record, what you're looking to do is update a current record. You need to use an `UPDATE` query, as follows:

```
$query = $conn->prepare( "UPDATE users SET steamusername = :steamusername WHERE username = :username" );
$query->execute(array( ':steamusername' => $steamusername, ':username' => $uname));
```

Notice that we pass the parameters to the `execute()` function as an array.

Comment: That fixed it, i also had a typo at the $stmt->bindvalue one, i had $stm1t :D Thanks :D